# Application Status

Tags: search

From the site patentscope.wipo.int I searched for a publication #.   The site made a find and when I clicked on the publication # the header had only five tabs on the header.  “National Biblo. Data”, “Description”, ”Claims”, ”Drawings”, ”Documents”.  It did not have a "National Phase" tab.  How can I determine the status of the application?  Thanks Steve

Comment: Can you provide the document number?